# Is it possible to override public method from private internal class?

Tags: java

There is the following problem: I have one internal private class which has got public method, and I need to override it. Is it possible using Java Reflection?

UPDATE:

```
public class MyPublicClass {

    private class MyPrivateClass {
        public void doPublicMethod() {}
    }
}
```

Comment: can you post the source code here?

Comment: Sorry, look at updates please

Comment: @Drogba, please, tell me, can you help?

Comment: No, it is not possible without some bytecode manipulation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I can think of is using a separate private class like this:

```
public class MyPublicClass {

    private class MyPrivateClass {
        public void doPublicMethod() {}
    }

    private class Test extends MyPrivateClass {
        @Override
        public void doPublicMethod() {
            // Do your stuff
        }
    }
}
```

But that is not using reflection.

Comment: Then, as Denis Tulskiy said in the comments, it's not possible by normal means.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible using reflection alone. But you might manage by using [AspectJ](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/) or another Aspect oriented programming lib for Java. It allows you to modify the bytecode using certain rules.